# Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got list)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code that works fine:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

text = [["Canada", 'University of California has great research', "non-location"],["China", 'MIT is at Boston', "non-location"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['text', 'text2', 'text3'])

col_list = df.columns 
for col in col_list:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(x).ents)])

df
```

However, when I do the same thing but with an additional number column I get the error: "Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got list)".

```
text = [["Canada", 'University of California has great research', "non-location", 2],["China", 'MIT is at Boston', "non-location", 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['text', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4'])

col_list = df.columns 

for col in col_list:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(x).ents)])
```

My question is how do I make it work with integers or simply ignore data columns that are of type integer?

Comment: Can you simplify this code to generate the problem without using pandas? (If not, add the `pandas` tag instead of using the `python` tag alone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are writing yourself the iteration over columns, it is easy to exclude columns that are of type int:

```
for col in col_list:
    if df[col].dtype == int:
        # ignore this column
        continue
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(x).ents)])
```

The following test (instead of `if df[col].dtype == int`) will exclude all numbers, booleans... but will not detect columns that are, like string columns, of `object` type:

```
if df[col].dtype != object
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If let say there is another data type 'float' within the data can I do "if df[col].dtype == int and df[col].dtype == float:" for the second line?

Comment: `or`, of course, not `and`, but yes, if you want to exclude only int and float ;) For a more general test, see my edit.